# FB API request without user login

Tags: android, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I want to get the [events list](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event/) from a public Facebook page, and to do it I need an access token. This is not a problem when doing it server-side, because I can use both my secret and client app id in order to get an access token, but this is not possible on client-side (for example, on an iOS application), since it would make clear my app secret ID. What can I do? With the Facebook SDK for iOS, I think I can only get an access token making the user log-in, but, in my case, this is not necessary, since I only need to get a public list of events.

With PHP:

```
require '../facebook-php-sdk/facebook.php'; //MY FACEBOOK SDK
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '<#MYAPPID#>',
    'secret' => '<#MYAPPSECRET#>', //<-- I CAN'T USE THIS ON CLIENT-SIDE!
));
```

Thanks

Comment: Public events is not means that you can get the events via API without access token. The doc at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event is stated that you must use access token. Another example, even a user is public, you have no guarantee to call API to get this user info, depends on various factors(e.g. turn off the platforms on user settings). For your case, you should request User access token, see this doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: I know that, my question was: how to get an access token on iOS/Android without asking the user to login?